# findByIdAndUpdate not updating the object Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, backend

I have the following code to update Users information by Id:

```
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.userId === req.params.id || req.body.isAdmin) {
    if (req.body.password) {
      try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
      } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json(err);
      }
    }
    try {
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: req.body });
      res.status(200).json("Account has been updated");
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json("You can update only your account!");
  }
});
```

I pass the new fields and findByIdAndUpdate is returning the catch error, I'm new to node and following a tutorial.

Comment: in which catch block (first or second) the error happens? And what does error say? Can you console.log(err) and update the question with the error?

Comment: I logged the error and turns out I have the User imported in a wrong way, fixed the issue thank you!